# Java GUI - How to append text to JTextArea from a static method?

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, static, non-static

I'm doing a simple exercise about client - server chat using Java IO. This is my code structure:

```
public class ChatRoomClientGUI{
    private JTextArea textAreaMessages;
    private JTextField textFieldMessage;
    private JButton buttonSendMsg;
    //...
    private static Socket socket = null;
    private static Scanner input = null;
    private static PrintWriter output = null;
    //...
    private static void handleInputStream(){
        String response = input.nextLine();
        textAreaMessages.append(response + "\n"); // Error here
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing now is that I can't get access to the `textAreaMessages` variable because it is **non-static** and the `handleInputStream()` method is **static**. I've tried some ways but none of them works:

- change `textAreaMessages;` to `private static JTextArea textAreaMessages;` => My IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) yield an error when I run the program
- change `handleInputStream()` to a *non-static* method => This didn't work either because I call this method from a static context and this can't be changed.

So any ideas how to fix this problem ?

Thanks so much in advanced !

Comment: Can you show some more code?

Comment: you can use : 

`StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Test");
      sb.append(" String Buffer");` and you bind "sb" to your textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fairly ugly, but *if* you're sure there is going to be only one instance of your object, then modify (or add) the constructor to set a static variable to `this`:

```
private static ChatRoomClientGUI singleton;
...
public ChatRoomClientGUI() {
    singleton = this;
    ...
}

private static void handleInputStream(){
    String response = input.nextLine();
    singleton.textAreaMessages.append(response + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create getter and setter for private `JTextArea textAreaMessages;` and while calling `handleInputStream`() pass the instance of this class and call the setter to append the text.

```
private static void handleInputStream(ChatRoomClientGUI gui) {
    String response = input.nextLine();
    gui.getTextField().append(response + "\n"); // Error here
}

public void setTextField(JTextField textField) {
    this.textAreaMessages = textField;
}

public JTextField getTextField() {
    return textAreaMessages;
}
```